VB.NET Overwriting Excel Worksheets
I’m using VB.NET and ClosedXML to open two Workbooks (Workbook1 and Workbook2). I then delete Sheet1 from Workbook1 and copy Sheet1 from Workbook2 into Workbook1. My code does this part fine however there are several tables on Sheet1 which lose data during this process. I’ve also tried deleting the tables from Workbook1 before importing the new Sheet1 in the hope that it would help but doesn’t make a difference. Essentially, Workbook2 is a master file which I use to overwrite Sheet1 on other files. I’m hoping someone can see what I’m doing wrong with my code.
Thanks in advance.
    Private Sub UpdateAllProductGlobals()

        Dim Answer As Integer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to update all Product Globals?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2)

        If Answer = vbNo Then
            Exit Sub
        Else

            Dim ProjectName As String = Get_Project_Name()

            Dim GlobalsFilePath As String = Get_Paths.Get_Project_Level_Globals_FilePath(ProjectName)
            Dim GlobalsWb As XLWorkbook = New XLWorkbook(GlobalsFilePath)
            Dim GlobalsWs As IXLWorksheet = GlobalsWb.Worksheet(Constants.wsGlobals)

            Dim RowNum As Integer
            Dim ProductName As String

            For RowNum = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

                ProductName = Get_Product_Name(RowNum)

                Dim ProductFilePath As String = Get_Paths.Get_Project_Level_Products_FilePath(ProjectName, ProductName)

                Dim ProductWb As XLWorkbook = New XLWorkbook(ProductFilePath)
                Dim ProductWs As IXLWorksheet = ProductWb.Worksheet(Constants.wsGlobals)

                For Each table In ProductWs.Tables
                    table.Delete(XLShiftDeletedCells.ShiftCellsUp)
                Next

                ProductWs.Delete()

                GlobalsWs.CopyTo(ProductWb, Constants.wsGlobals, 1)

                With ProductWb
                    .Save()
                    .Dispose()
                End With

                ProductName = Nothing
                ProductWs = Nothing
                ProductWb = Nothing
                ProductFilePath = Nothing
            Next

            GlobalsWb.Dispose()
            MsgBox("All Products Updated")

        End If

    End Sub

